# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification not fired

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, icloud, key-value

i just released my app and realized that `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification` is not fired.
I need it that it is fired the first time a user open the app to register him (and check if it was already a user before).

The problem is that, if the notification isn't fired, then my app will be stuck.

I'm using key-value and it's properly setted in Xcode

Now, with my iphone, with developer profile, everything works great.
With a distribution profile, it does not.

I already have a production profile with icloud enabled (and app id with icloud enabled too).

In my app, this two parameters,even in the app store version, are fine:

```
    _currentiCloudToken = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];
    _myUbiquityContainer = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil];
```

Here's my code:

```
- (id)initWithCloudStore:(NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *) store {

    if ((self = [super init])) {

        _iCloudStore = store;
        _currentiCloudToken = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];
        _myUbiquityContainer = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(storeDidChange:)
                                                     name:NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification
                                                   object:_iCloudStore];
    }
    return self;

}

-(BOOL) iCloudIsEnabled {
    if(_currentiCloudToken && _myUbiquityContainer != nil) return TRUE;
    else return FALSE;
}

-(void) sync {
    if([_iCloudStore synchronize]) NSLog(@"iCloud Sync OK");
}


-(void) storeDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification  {


    NSString *iCloudUUID = [_iCloudStore objectForKey:userUUIDKey];

    if(iCloudUUID != nil) {
        NSLog(@"iCloud UUID present with value %@",iCloudUUID);
        //[[iCloudHelper sharedInstance] removeObjectForKey:userUUIDKey];
        // sostituisco uuid locale con quello di icloud
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:iCloudUUID forKey:userUUIDKey];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    } else {
        // salvo uuid in iCloud
        NSLog(@"UUID not present on iCloud");
        [_iCloudStore setObject:[self createNewUUID] forKey:userUUIDKey];
    }

    int reason = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreChangeReasonKey] intValue];

    if(reason == NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreInitialSyncChange) {
        NSLog(@"This was the initial sync");

    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"iCloudDone" object:nil];

}
```

What I'm missing?